# VSCode inline diff peek view doesn't show whitespace difference

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I change the indentation, `Diff Decorations Gutter` shows that this line is modified, and `open changes with previous revision` shows the whitespace difference.

However, when I click the decoration gutter, there is no diff in peek view. How to show the whitespace diff in peek view?

VSCode version: 1.69.2

My settings:

SCM: Diff Decorations Ignore Trim Whitespace - false

Diff Editor: Ignore Trim Whitespace - false

[Decorations Gutter & inline diff peek view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ49d.png)

[open changes with previous revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Bz1.png)